# can you get the Gem object to return a list of available gems in the path?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, webserver

I am having issues getting my local gems to work on my web server. I keep getting no such file to load errors even though I have added my local gem dir to my .gemrc paths. I am hoping to find a way to at least see what gems I DO have access to.

I have tried adding my local gem path a couple ways including

```
Gem.path.push "/myHome/usrName/ruby/gems
```

with no luck. How do I do something like

```
Gem.available_gems.each do |g|
 puts g
end
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/).  It manages your gems for you and lets your project know where to find them when employed properly.  On production servers it can install a local copy of the gem so that you don't need to worry about setting up your path vars correctly.

Comment: thanks for the pointer. I have been using bundler but in the end had to switch servers from WebHostingPad.com to RackSpace.com. Webhostingpad didn't allow me any real access to install anything let only use gcc for larger installs. Rackspace gives me all that an more for just a few bucks a month more.